# Difference between MTU and Burst at Linux-TC

Tags: networking, tc

I did a small experiment by using `Linux-tc`

My question is what is the difference between Burst and MTU at `Linux tc-htb`

It seems that they have a same effect. They change a only burst value.

(we can see by using this command `tc -s -s -d c ls dev <iface>` )

However, two page say differently.

1) [**HTB - Traffic control How to**](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/classful-qdiscs.html) said

> **burst**    max bytes burst which can be accumulated during idle period {computed}
>
> **mtu**  max packet size we create rate map for {1600}

2) [**MAN tc-tbf page**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-tbf.8.html) said

> **burst**  Also known as buffer or maxburst.  Size of the bucket, in
>                 bytes. ...
>
> **mtu/minburst** Specifies the size of the peakrate bucket.

Is it right that they have a different explanation but same effect?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, It looks same when looking `linux tc` source code.

Two option change the variable 'buffer'.

In detail, HTB change the variable 'buffer' when using the options  `mtu` and `burst`

However TBF change the variable 'buffer' when using the option  `burst`

but the variable 'mtu' when using the option `mtu`

But I need to study what it means, more deeply.

**[1] /tc/q_tbf.c**

```
static int tbf_parse_opt(struct qdisc_util *qu, int argc, char **argv,
             struct nlmsghdr *n, const char *dev)
{
...
        } else if (matches(*argv, "burst") == 0 ||
            strcmp(*argv, "buffer") == 0 ||
            strcmp(*argv, "maxburst") == 0) {
            const char *parm_name = *argv;

            NEXT_ARG();
            if (buffer) {
                fprintf(stderr, "tbf: duplicate \"buffer/burst/maxburst\" specification\n");
                return -1;
            }
            if (get_size_and_cell(&buffer, &Rcell_log, *argv) < 0) {
                explain1(parm_name, *argv);
                return -1;
            }
...
        } else if (strcmp(*argv, "mtu") == 0 ||
               strcmp(*argv, "minburst") == 0) {
            const char *parm_name = *argv;

            NEXT_ARG();
            if (mtu) {
                fprintf(stderr, "tbf: duplicate \"mtu/minburst\" specification\n");
                return -1;
            }
            if (get_size_and_cell(&mtu, &Pcell_log, *argv) < 0) {
                explain1(parm_name, *argv);
                return -1;
            }
...
    opt.buffer = tc_calc_xmittime(opt.rate.rate, buffer);

    if (opt.peakrate.rate) {
        opt.peakrate.mpu      = mpu;
        opt.peakrate.overhead = overhead;
        if (tc_calc_rtable(&opt.peakrate, ptab, Pcell_log, mtu, linklayer) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "tbf: failed to calculate peak rate table.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        opt.mtu = tc_calc_xmittime(opt.peakrate.rate, mtu);
    }

...
}
```

**[2] /tc/q_htb.c**

```
static int htb_parse_class_opt(struct qdisc_util *qu, int argc, char **argv, struct nlmsghdr *n, const char *dev)
...
        } else if (matches(*argv, "burst") == 0 ||
               strcmp(*argv, "buffer") == 0 ||
               strcmp(*argv, "maxburst") == 0) {
            NEXT_ARG();
            if (get_size_and_cell(&buffer, &cell_log, *argv) < 0) {
                explain1("buffer");
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (matches(*argv, "cburst") == 0 ||
               strcmp(*argv, "cbuffer") == 0 ||
               strcmp(*argv, "cmaxburst") == 0) {
            NEXT_ARG();
            if (get_size_and_cell(&cbuffer, &ccell_log, *argv) < 0) {
                explain1("cbuffer");
                return -1;
            }
        } else if 
..


...
    if (!buffer)
        buffer = rate64 / get_hz() + mtu;
    if (!cbuffer)
        cbuffer = ceil64 / get_hz() + mtu;
...
}


static int htb_print_opt(struct qdisc_util *qu, FILE *f, struct rtattr *opt)
{
...
        if (show_details) {
            fprintf(f, "burst %s/%u mpu %s ",
                sprint_size(buffer, b1),
                1<<hopt->rate.cell_log,
                sprint_size(hopt->rate.mpu, b2));
            fprintf(f, "cburst %s/%u mpu %s ",
                sprint_size(cbuffer, b1),
                1<<hopt->ceil.cell_log,
                sprint_size(hopt->ceil.mpu, b2));
            fprintf(f, "level %d ", (int)hopt->level);
        } else {

...
}
```